# Simple email contact form

Tags: php, html, css, form-submit

I am implementing a simple email input form into a splash page for submission.

I know I need a post form, and have the html fully implemented (I think) per this:

```
<div id="main">
    <form method="post" action="">
        <div id="text">
            Please enter your email address here, and we will get back to you
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="q" id="search" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Go!" />
    </form>
</div>
```

My css follows as:

```
#main input {
    margin: 30px auto auto 130px ;
    positiom: absolute;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 3px;
    padding: 6px;
    z-index: 3;  
   }
#search {
    float: left;
    width: 550px;
   }
#submit {
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    margin: 130px auto auto 200px ;
   }
#submit::-moz-focus-inner { 
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I have a web server with apache, php, etc... installed and am trying to figure out the next step to finishing my form.  I would want this to function as a form that sends individual emails to a specific gmail account each time someone enters their address.  Beyond a webserver, do I need additional tools to accomplish this?  I have read up on numerous sites about 3rd party forms that goes through their sites but am worried about the security and would rather have my site transfer all of the data.  Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a PHP script to handle sending the email. In your HTML, change the action:

```
<form method="post" action="sendmail.php">
```

And create a sendmail.php file with:

```
<?php

$email = addcslashes($_REQUEST['q']) ;

mail( "yourname@example.com", "E-Mail entered",
"E-Mail entered: $email");
header( "Location: http://www.example.com/thankyou.html" );
?>
```

Edited: Added addclashes()

Comment: If you go this route, and you should, be sure to sanitize all of your data! Never just operate on values directly pulled from $_POST / $_GET, etc

Comment: Ok so I am closer than I thought!  When you say sanitize, what do you mean? =p

Comment: To avoid injections. A malicious user could add some characters as his/her email address that could trigger bad results. I would use addcslashes() or urlencode()

Comment: Ok great!  And the header method is the redirect that points the user to the followup page?